# I am doing phone number login with firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

This is error I am getting .com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]
I have enabled firebase phone login option and also added google-service.gson file.I tried everything.Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added the SHA Certificate Fingerprint to your Firebase Console?
 Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#before-you-begin

Comment: Yes I have done but still gettting error

Comment: Check if the project_id in your Android app google-services.json file is the same as the Firebase project for which you enabled the Auth and I hope you are not trying this on emulator

Comment: Yes it is same in google-service.json file and in my project as well and I have enabled Auth for phone and I am using my android phone not emulator.I am still getting error An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]

Comment: I would suggest you recreate the project and see if error persists.

Comment: Not working I created 3 times

Comment: Have you tested other  Firebase services also? Try this sample project https://github.com/coozgan/TestingPhoneAuth

Comment: I am checking TestingPhoneAuth. I think problem is with  SHA Certificate Fingerprint and trying

Comment: I checked TestingPhoneAuth code as well.Same result.I think problem is with SHA Certificate Fingerprint steps and I am trying and will not give up.Thanks

Comment: Hello All,If anyone is reading.I have resolved issue.Solution is open cmd terminal as administrator then enter this command "keytool -exportcert -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Amol\.android\debug.keystore" Here it is my pc .android folder address you have to put your pc address then it will ask for password.Password is "android" then your problem will resolve  An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]

Comment: Yes the problem was with the valid SHA certificate